# iis 7 web deploy / source control interaction problem

Tags: asp.net, tortoisesvn, deployment

I have an asp.net web application that I am deploying using ms web deploy to an iis 7 web server.

I recently moved the project to source control with tortoise svn.  Now web deploy isn't working since it is trying to copy the hidden read-only files (in a .svn subdirectory) that svn is using onto the iis server.

How do I configure web deploy to leave these files alone?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind more of an X-copy scenario if you get your applications root folder and right-click drag it to another folder you will get the option - SVN Export all items here, or you can use SVN Export versioned items only, which will ignore all unversioned files.

This will do a clean export to the new folder with all .svn files removed!

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120629025549/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-application-s-project-file.aspx)

The first comment specifically about the line

**.svn***.*

was the key.